# An Alamofire request for each cell of a table view

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, alamofire

I want to populate a table view by parsing JSON data received thanks to several Alamofire requests. However, the thing is that each cell has a different request from the others. Each cell makes a request based on IndexPath. Since the calls are asynchronous, not all requests are achieved...

My code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    var name = ""
    let url = "https://........"+items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]+"......"

    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
            let object = swiftyJsonVar["results"][0]
            print(object)
            name = object["name"].stringValue
            cell.textLabel?.text = name
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

How would it be possible to achieve every request? Thanks in advance!

Comment: the thing is that cellForRowAt is not keeping the data and as you scroll up and down is making the request again and again and again.... so maybe you have to consider caching data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep track of hooking indexpath with every request so you know what the value returned is for

```
 struct Item
{
    var indexPath:NSIndexPath!

  func getData(index:NSIndexPath)
  {

      let url = "https://........"+items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]+"......"

      Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
    if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
        let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
        let object = swiftyJsonVar["results"][0]

         globalArr// store indexpath and value

         /// remove indexoath from allDownloads

         /// send refresh to table

      }
     }

  }

}
```

in cell for row

```
     if(indexPath in globalArr)
      {
         // show it
      }
      else
      { 

           // check whether it's download is in progress to avoid multiple same requests when scroll because of dequeuing 
         if(allDownloads doesn't contain inexpath)
         {

              // create object of item and start download

              // allDownloads.add(object)

          }

       }
```

globalArr: keep track of all downloaded objects

allDownloads : keep track of in progress downloads

Comment: Alright, I understand your solution but will it allow me to make several Alamofire requests?

Comment: use , it will create object for every request

Comment: The array allDownloads is the same as globalArr??

Comment: Thanks! So in the second part of code, you should've written if(indexPath in globalArr) right?